# Scrolling while message box is running

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following macro to show a message box to the user:

```
Sub Messageboxtest()
Test = MsgBox("Do you want to continue", vbYesNo)
If Answer = vbYes Then
Sheets(1).Range("A2").Value = 1
Else
End If
End Sub
```

The macro itself works perfectly. However, once the message box is shown on the excel screen the user cannot scroll down in the Excel File anymore.

For an input box I know there is the function `Application.InputBox` but is there also something like `Application.MessageBox`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not a application.MessageBox function just the MsgBox, but you can create a form that looks like a MsgBox and set the ShowModal property to False

Answer (score 0):

There's API alternative! Declare in a top of module this function:

```
#If VBA7 Then
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function ModelessMsgBox Lib "User32" Alias "MessageBoxA" (Optional ByVal hWnd As Long, _
            Optional ByVal prompt As String, _
            Optional ByVal title As String, _
            Optional ByVal buttons As Long) As Long
#Else
    Public Declare Function ModelessMsgBox Lib "User32" Alias "MessageBoxA" (Optional ByVal hWnd As Long, _
            Optional ByVal prompt As String, _
            Optional ByVal title As String, _
            Optional ByVal buttons As Long) As Long
#End If
```

And use it like this:

```
Call ModelessMsgBox(prompt:="MsgBox!!!!", buttons:=vbYesNo)
```

However, this MsgBox stops code execution (when modeless forms doesn't, dooming you to use another garbage set of global/static variables and/or to supress events just to control execution flow), so it can be used like this:

```
If ModelessMsgBox(prompt:="MsgBox!!!!", buttons:=vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
    'do smth
Else
    'do smth else
End If
```

More [here](http://allapi.mentalis.org/apilist/MessageBox.shtml)